# how to fetch data in react based on the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

on a button-click i am changing a value of a state property based on that value i want to fetch the data. 
Issue I am facing is that, data is fetched before the state change even after calling it after the set state method. Due to which data is fetched based on the previous value of the state.
(new to react please help)

Comment: Show us what you did so far, please. And state your problem clearly

Comment: Hi shiva can you show sample code ?, then only we can suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right. You want to use the updated value of a state.

You can use callback method of setState.

For example -

```
this.setState({item1: 25}, ()={
 // now use your updated state in your code...
 console.log(this.state.item1); // will give you new value of item1
})
```

Comment: It worked for me. i dont know how should i thankyou. You are saviour.

Comment: If it worked for you. Could you please upvote and approve it?